# How to avoid conflict of variable names in sub classes or classes including modules in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
module M
  def func1_in_M
    @some_popular_name = 'some data needed for M'
  end

  def func2_in_M
    p @some_popular_name
  end
end

class C
  include M

  def initilaize
    @some_popular_name = "some data needed for C, but this guy didn't know what are used in M"
  end

  def func1_in_C
    p @some_popular_name
  end
end

o = C.new
o.func1_in_M
o.func1_in_C # => "some data needed for M"
```

This result is obviously not the one which coder of class C expected. This kind of problem could easily happen with multi-module mixing/multi-sub-classing as well. Is any good suggestion to avoid this? @**var... still could cause the same. name-mangling-related-to-module.__id**? how?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation will defeat the purpose of including a module. Including a module means that you are giving the functionality of the included module to the class, which are methods and instance variables.

If you expect the programmer of class `C` to be unaware of what is happening in `M`, then you should not include `M` into `C` or subclass `C` from `M`. Rather, you should delegate some functions to `M` from `C`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I think this is kind of some disadvantage of Ruby (less encapsulation) as Matz thought that introduction of private instance vars (but not released one which have that feature yet). As you said, yes, we could say that instance variables in modules are also part of protocol/contract between the modules and user class.